# What is a best way for render only view without loading layout everytime in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to render view without loading layout everytime. What is a best way? 
P.S. Using Partial View is not solution for me.

Comment: Best way is to don't use layout if you don't need it. You may want to clarify your question to explain what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: No, I need layout. But I don't want load layout everytime, I need something as AJAX UpdatePanel (in ASP.NET Web Forms).

Comment: Are you only wanting a layout to load under certain criteria? If this, load the layout, otherwise don't load the layout?

Comment: So set Layout = "" at beginning of your view.

Comment: What you're talking about is essentially a SPA (single page application). For that, you essentially move all the functions MVC performs to the client side using something like Angular to perform your routing, data access, handling views (javascript templates), etc. At which point, MVC itself becomes pretty pointless. Traditionally, for a SPA, it will be backed by something like Web Api, rather than MVC, because all you need is a way to get at the data.

Comment: Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2):

you want your view to be processed and your layout to be static (like cached) and just refresh the part inside layout.  no you cant. when a page is posted, everything(whole page) is cleared(except some specific things like cookies) and the page is prepared for the server response. it is possible with full ajax site. or as a strange and expensive solution, you can save your layout page in a cookie then you return null in layout if cookie is set(as etr mentioned).you read it from cookie, or in a similar way, you try client side cache. a web browser is not your application, you cant say "this part should keep position, just change this part".without using xmlhttprequest or websocket, every page is a request-response couple.

Answer (score 1):

If you want for example that in a ajax request to not be loaded, then you first check if the request is an Ajax request by modyfing:

```
In ~/Views/ViewStart.cshtml
```

like below:

```
@{
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

and in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say how you'd want your Layout to load sometimes, but at the top of your view you can check criteria:

```
@{
    if (/* your criteria here */) {
        Layout = "path to your layout file";
    } else {
        Layout = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You must delete Layout at the View or _ViewStart.